# SSL error not occuring in IOS 10.3

Tags: ios, app-transport-security, ios10.3

In our app ATS is enabled and we are using a server that is **not using TLS 1.2**.

In ios 10.1 and 10.2 when trying to connect this server,connection fails with the below error.

This is **not observed in iOS 10.3**. Connection is establishing normally

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didFailWithError:(NSError *)aError
```

Error

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x170649ed0
{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://************, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,
_kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://****************, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://*************, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://**************, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

My question is why connection is establishing in 10.3 even though server is not using TLS 1.2. Is there any changes to ATS, TLS version 1.2 mandatory , or NSAllowLocalNetworking in ios 10.3 update

Comment: Do you have a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Need more details.  Is this a local network resource?  Self-signed cert? What are your App Transport Security settings in your Info.plist?